# Convert string-tuple to a tuple

Tags: python, string, tuples, type-conversion

I have an input file with the following format:

```
[(1,1),(2,1)], 'add', 11
[(1,2),(1,3)], 'div', 2
[(3,1),(4,1),(3,2),(4,2)], 'times', 240
[(2,2),(2,3)], 'minus', 3
...
```

Each line is a tuple I want to create. How is it possible to convert each string line into a tuple?

For example, line `string "[(1,1),(2,1)], 'add', 11"` should be converted to a tuple: `([(1, 1), (2, 1)], 'add', 11)`.

So far, I tried:

```
tuples = []
for line in file:
    tuples.append((line,))
```

But I am getting a string conversion

```
 [("[(1,1),(2,1)], 'add', 11\n",), ("[(1,2),(1,3)], 'div', 2\n",), ("[(3,1),(4,1),(3,2),(4,2)], 'times', 240\n",), ("[(2,2),(2,3)], 'minus', 3",)]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) as:

```
>>> import ast
>>> my_string = "[(1,1),(2,1)], 'add', 11"

>>> ast.literal_eval(my_string)
([(1, 1), (2, 1)], 'add', 11)
```

As per the [`ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.