# Adding tuples to a list without them gaining quotation marks?

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have some variables that look something like this:

```
Word1 = list[0]
Word2 = list[2]
```

Each variable will output this when printed:

```
print(Word1)
#prints ('Example 1', 5, 10, 15, 20)
print(Word2)
#prints ('Example 2', 10, 20, 13, 17)
```

but as soon as I add these to a list, they gain quotation marks around them

```
NewList.append(Word1)
NewList.append(Word2)
#Newlist becomes ["('Example 1', 5, 10, 15, 20)", "('Example 2', 10, 20, 13, 17)"] when printed.
```

Is there any way I can remove the quotation marks that appear when adding them to a list, so that `NewList` can look like this:

```
[('Example 1', 5, 10, 15, 20), ('Example 2', 10, 20, 13, 17)]
```

Comment: What is type of Word1 and Word2 ?

Comment: Duplicate of: [Convert string-tuple to a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150857/convert-string-tuple-to-a-tuple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval`

```
Word1 = eval(list[0])
Word2 = eval(list[2])

NewList.append(Word1)
NewList.append(Word2)
```

Output:

```
[('Example 1', 5, 10, 15, 20), ('Example 2', 10, 20, 13, 17)]
```

*Hope this answers your question!!!*